# Can Reporting service on sql server web edition running on azure virtual machine use the azure database as the data source?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

Since the azure database not support the reporting service anymore, I have to use a reporting service on a sql server running on an azure virtual machine to get the reporting service for my azure websites.  The azure websites uses the reporting service web services to provides the report functions to users.

My question is,  Can the web edition work for that purpose? Or has to be at least standard edition.

The standard edition even for 1 core costs 410$ per month + the virtual machine cost.  Which does not make any sense to me at all, because we only use the reporting services on that sql server running on the virtual machine.

Can web edition reporting service connect to the azure database as the data source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have Standard Edition or higher for connecting to remote data sources.

In Web Edition Reporting Services only supports connecting to a local Web Edition of SQL Server DbEngine.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx#Reporting

Comment: with the reporting service taking away from azure database, wish there is better way to handle this with cost in mind